# Formatting Hard Drives Takes Ages

Tags: format

I am formatting my hard drive using the "disks" utility. I selected my 3TB hard drive and chose the option not to partition it, but do a complete full erase (i.e. not the quick-erase option). It reckons that it will take 14 hours to complete. Can someone explain why it takes this long? In Windows it use to take about 5 seconds, but I have a feeling that it must not have truly formatted it or something.

Comment: You explain it yourself: you choose complete full erase. this means everything will be overwritten=3TB. that's slow. complete overwrite in windos will roughly take the same amount of time. unless you choose quick-format.

Comment: `(3000 * 1000)Mb / (50Mb/s) / 3600 = 16.7 hours`, so it's reasonable.

Answer (score 10):

**Quick format vs full format**

Formatting is the process of setting up a *filesystem* on a *partition*.

A quick format does the minimal number of steps to establish a new, empty filesystem on the partition.  This involves writing small structures to certain specific locations on the drive, but it does not write to the rest of the drive at all.  If there is data on the rest of the drive, it remains untouched, but unused and not visible to the user, until new files are written to that area.

The time to perform a quick format depends on the filesystem type, but typically takes a few seconds, and is almost always less than a minute.

A full format does the same steps but also wipes the rest of the drive by settings its contents to zeroes.  The speed of this can depend on the drive, and may take hours because it needs to, at least, write the full drive's capacity to the drive.  This can sometimes be very slow.  For example, a 4TB drive connected over USB 2.0 is likely to take over 25 hours for a full format.  A fast internal drive may take several hours, though if it's a fast SSD connected over NVMe it may take substantially less.

In any case, it's a time-consuming process of dubious necessity with few benefits.  It makes it harder to recover the previous data on the drive, but not as well as specialized secure deletion tools.  It also may detect some kinds of errors on the drive that a quick format wouldn't, though if error checking is a goal there are better tools for it, and the errors it would detect are ones that would be detected and reported as you write to the drive naturally.  There are some claims that it "exercises" or "freshens" the drive surface, but this is largely superstition and doesn't take into account the way the drive works.

If you want your format to take only a matter of seconds, choose a quick format.

**Interrupting a full format**

It's safe to interrupt a full format before it has finished and then perform a quick format.

**Low level formatting**

Once upon a time hard drives came without their pattern of tracks and sectors laid out on the disk yet and you did this yourself using a software tool.

New hard drives come with their entire surface ready-to-use and there is no longer any way to alter it this at a low level or to initialize it in any way.  So-called "low level formatting" is a myth at this point.

Complicating this myth is that there exist tools that claim to be able to do it.  They don't, though.  What they actually do could be a combination of just a regular full format, just "faking it", an erase or "secure erase", or in the best case, setting some manufacturer-specific drive performance parameters or updating drive firmware, none of which is the kind of low-level format that was once possible.

Comment: "New hard drives come pre-formatted" What do you mean by that? New drives do heavily rely on on-the-fly error correction and relocating sectors according to Steve Gibson in his podcast. The platters may be checked for quality but accessing the drive is mostly opportunistic by detecting errors during writing.

Comment: Also please don't mention "low level format" tools, this is almost an urban legend today where the controller and the firmware handle everything. By mentioning such a thing you just keep the myth alive that these things exist for modern drives or even have a purpose. Everyone who has access to engineering tools directly from the manufacturer should know how to handle these, shouldn't ask such a naive question here and if they know how these things work they are probably under NDA. For the rest of us it's just an anecdote that doesn't apply to Ubuntu's audience and current platforms it runs on.

Comment: By saying new drives come pre-formatted I mean that you do not have to perform any initialization to them in order to use them; ie the idea that you must do a "full" format to a new drive is a myth.  Good point about mentioning low level format tools, I've edited.

Comment: Ironically enough I've added in a new section all about low level formatting because misinformation on this is so prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in windows you only rewrite some blocks, which are crucial to read the files and in ubuntu when you "fully rewrite" it could actually mean rewrite all the 3TB with zeros. You can check your disk's write speed and divide 3TB by it and you should get cca that much if my thoughts are right (or a bit less). But I'm no pro, so any answers covering this have a high risk of getting +1 from me :D

Hope I helped at least a bit :)

Comment: While Windows can do a quick format, it can also do a full format as well. You just uncheck [the quick format check box](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=windows+%22quick+format%22).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes disk creator or gparted messes up my USB  stick so I quick format it with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1
```

It is very quick writing 512 bytes to remove the MBR (Master Boot Record).

In simple terms you changed count size from 1 to 6 billion. This is normally only done when you dispose of an old drive with financial secrets.

You can safely abort the long format and restart with creating partitions only.