# Disks Application Formatting

Tags: format, disk-utility

In the Formatting Option in the Disks application for Ubuntu 14.04, it gives the option to not overwrite existing data or overwrite existing data with 0's. I've tried both, and both clear the disk and all its data. So what exactly is the difference? What is the point of using the second one, as it takes SO much longer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Hard Drives Takes Ages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638262/formatting-hard-drives-takes-ages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not overwriting existing data, the file tables are cleared and all of the diskspace is opened up for future writing.  The data is still there, but won't be seen by the new filesystem.  The old data will become corrupted and overwritten over time.  This is typically faster, and fine for a normal user.

When overwriting existing data, every bit of the device is written over with a zero.  This is preferred when the contents of the disk were confidential, or the drive is being given to another person.  In this way, the data is more securely destroyed (not entirely) and would be much, much harder to get off the disk.